# Is there a better way to call each derived object's method for a base class?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, derived-class

I have a base class where I derive several classes. I have another class that uses all those derived classes in a different way. However, I want to call the `Update()` method (inherited from the base class) on each derived class. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to do something like:

```
dim a As Derived1
a.Update

dim b As Derived2
b.Update

etc...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to keep the derived objects in a list of some kind, and then iterate over them to call Update.

In pseudo-code:

```
foreach BaseClass item in {a, b, ...}:
    item.Update
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that through polymorphism with a function call that's passed the base class (pseudo-code):

```
Dim Dev1 as Derived1 '// This is derived from the class BaseClass
Dim Dev2 as Derived2 '// This is derived from the class BaseClass

CallUpdate(Dev1)
CallUpdate(Dev2)

Function CallUpdate(BaseClass bc)
    bc.Update()
End Function
```

Comment: You're just trading .Update for CallUpdate.  What's the benefit?

Comment: I was abstracting the BaseClass functionality through the function call.  I read the OP as asking if there was a way to call BaseClass functionality in a common way.

Comment: no, i know how to do that, hence stating that the `Update` method is inherited. I want a way to call all the derived classes' `Update` method at once.

Comment: @Jason - then you want recursive's answer. :)